# how to get around when normal index or bitmap index isn't useful

Tags: oracle, indexing, partitioning

The columns that are in the where clause are not selective. They are all in 1 single table. In addition the expressions used are NOT EQUAL, OR, IS NULL, IS NOT NULL. The primary key is on the customer ID. I am not sure how to get around with this kind of data. Are there different indexing methods that can be created on table or other ways to solve the problem. I guess partitions won't be helpful either for breaking a table into one major section with large data. Any thoughts or workarounds will be useful.

I'm putting below the data for reference and sample queries for ease of understanding.

[image]

sample query
colA = 'Marketable' OR colA is null
NORMAL index: gets ignored due to OR and NULL operator. Moreover the queried data covers more than 95% of data in the table.
BITMAP index: gets ignored due to more than 96% data coverage.

[image]

sample query
colB = '7' OR colB = '6' OR colB = '5'
NORMAL or BITMAP: both not useful due to large data selection. Optimizer goes with full table scan using the primary key cust_id.

[image]

sample query
colC <> 'SPECIAL SEGMENT'  OR colC is null (since the values can change, no specific value is passed)

combination sample query
NOT (colB = '6' OR colB = '3') AND
(colC <> 'SPECIAL SEGMENT'  OR colC is null)

Answer (score 3):

Full table scans are not evil.  Index access is not always more efficient.

If you want to return the majority of the data in a table, you want to use a full table scan since that's the most efficient way of accessing large fractions of the data in the table.  Indexes are great when you want to access relatively small fractions of the data in the table.  But if you want most of the data, doing millions of index accesses is not going to be more efficient.  In your first example, you want to return 9.2 million rows from a 9.3 million row table.  A full table scan is the plan you want-- that's the most efficient way to retrieve 99% of the rows in the table.  Anything else is going to be less efficient.  You could, I suppose, potentially partition the table on `A` leading to full partition scans of the two large partitions.  That's only going to cut, say 1% of the work your query needs to do, though, and may have negative impacts on other queries on that table.

Now, I'm always a bit suspicious about queries that want to return 99% of the rows in a table in the first place.  It would make no sense to have such a query in an OLTP system, for example, because no human is going to page through 9.2 million rows of data.  It wouldn't make sense to have that sort of query if the goal is to replicate data because it would almost certainly be more efficient to just replicate incremental changes rather than the entire data set every time.  It might make sense to read almost all the rows if the goal is to perform some aggregations.  But if this is something that happens enough to care about optimizing the analysis, you'd be better off looking at ways of pre-aggregating the data using materialized views and dimensions so that you can read and aggregate the data once and then just read your pre-aggregated values at runtime.

If you do really need to read all that data, you may also want to look into parallel query.  If there are relatively few readers, it is more efficient to let Oracle do the full scan in parallel so that your session can utilize more of the available hardware.  Of course, that means that you can have fewer simultaneous sessions since more hardware for you means less for others, so that's a trade-off you need to understand.  If you're building an ETL process where there will only be a couple sessions loading data at any point, parallel query can provide substantial performance improvements.

Comment: Thank you for your response Justin.  Can you please guide me on how can I enable "parallel query" to run on the database or where I can read further on it?